# Can Watin work with IE edge?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, watin

I am unable to get a single proper document based on this topic.

As far as I know, Watin works well with Internet Explorer and Firefox (with some exceptions).

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? The question seems a little unclear at the moment

Comment: I am able to extract data from webpage in IE (browser) through Watin.But i want to know whether the same is possible in Microsoft Edge browser?

Comment: Why don't you try it out

Comment: but i am using windows 7 .Can i be able to download Microsoft Edge browser for Windows 7?

Comment: @MuzammilAnsari Have you tried downloading edge browser to see if it runs on Windows 7?

Comment: @Izzy There is no edge browser for Windows 7.

Comment: try to download the Win10 with Edge VM so you can test it out https://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/windows/

Answer (score 0):

Officially, Watin does not support Edge and, as a matter of fact, it does not officially support anything above Windows 7.  With that being said, it works all the way through Windows 10 (with some quirks in edge cases and certain environment setups).  The same flexibility does not extend to Edge, as there is no official support and I haven't seen any work done for it.  You might be able to write your wrapper to work with the existing base, but it's probably not what you're aiming at.

As an aside, you might want to consider Selenium, if that is possible in your scenario, as there is a pretty good communication channel between the Selenium team and the Edge team, and the support is official on both ends (https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/).  Note that the Selenium team does do any work on the MS's WebDriver themselves.  All that and the fact that I rarely see anything in Watin development... might as well be a dead project, but that's my personal thought on the matter and should be taken with a grain of salt (the team is very small, after all... I think it's down to one developer at the moment).